# mini-profiler javascript and css includes are not returned

Tags: servicestack

Included code in global.asax to start and stop profiling.

When I view a page there are failed requests to load ssr-jquip, ssr-includes (javascript and css).

This worked before - last time I looked at it was a couple of versions of service stack ago.

What do I need to do or have to get these files to be delivered by servicestack.net?

[image: Request Failures]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that if you change your ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath and use a path that starts with a forward slash, the script references generated by mini profiler are incorrect.

So, for example, if you do this:

            `var endpointHostConfig = new EndpointHostConfig
            {
                ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "/newpath",
            };`

then you reference localhost:2343/newpath/someApiCall
Then mini profiler will emit references to newpath/ssr-includes.css which is not correct.

Changing your code to this:

            `var endpointHostConfig = new EndpointHostConfig
            {
                ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "newpath",
            };`

Solves it.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this problem using the following syntax too:

```
Profiler.Settings.RouteBasePath = "~/newpath";
```